# How do I pass input as an argument when I'm in the gdb shell?

Tags: c, io, gdb

So hypothetical case here, let's say I have to programs named:

prog1.c

prog2.c

Now, prog1.c is first compiled and ran as this:

```
gcc -Wall prog1.c
./a.exe 20 5 > out
```

So now I have an output file called "out" that is read in binary. Now, I need to take in the file into prog2.c, so I normally do so:

```
gcc -Wall prog2.c
./a.exe 3 2 < out
```

The problem here is that I'm running into pretty bad problems with prog2.c and I need to use gdb to debug it. The problem here is that whenever I try to pass in the out file, gdb just doesn't let me.

```
Reading symbols from ./a.exe...done.
(gdb) r 3 1 < out
Starting program: /drives/C/Users/XX/XXXXX~1/a.exe 3 1 < out
[New Thread 4632.0x83c]
[New Thread 4632.0x1f40]
Usage: prog2 sort-field [sort-type]

[Inferior 1 (process 4632) exited with code 01]
```

gdb seems to keep stopping whenever I try to pass in the out file and gives me the Inferior 1 (process 4632) error. Is there a way I can pass this in properly?  I tried using set args and it didn't work (or maybe I did it wrong).

Thanks

Comment: Please show your code for prog2. The gdb log shows that it is correctly redirecting to your program but your program is failing some sort of check, printing the usage and exiting. In other words, are you sure it is the redirect and not the arguments that are the problem?

Comment: can you please provide the out put of ./a.exe 3 2 < out . GDB starting your programm ( Starting program: /drives/C/Users/XX/XXXXX~1/a.exe 3 1 < out) properly.